# Customize constellation diagram of Smart diagram

Tags: beamer, diagrams, smartdiagram

I am using the constellation diagram of Smart diagram in Beamer, the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette 
 quaternary}%               
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }
 } 

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{test} 
 \smartdiagramset{
 planet size=3cm,
 planet text width=2.5cm,
 planet font=\footnotesize,
 satellite size=2cm, 
 satellite text width=2.5cm,
 satellite font=\scriptsize,
 distance planet-text=0,
 %distance satellite-text=0,
 distance planet-satellite=3.5cm,
 /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
 } 
 \begin{center}
 \scalebox{0.8}{
 \smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  Conditions de simulation,
  Type de tâches,
  Contraintes temporelles,
  Test de faisabilité du GEDF,
  Contraintes systèmes,
  Contraintes énergétiques}}
  \end{center}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

I obtained the following diagram

[image]

I want

1. to make the words in the satellites darker to be clear.
2. to reduce the distance between the text and the borders of the satellites.
3. to delete the arrows
4. to make the satellites appear one by one

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that `smartdiagram` is great if you want a diagram in one of the styles it creates. However, if you want something not in its style box, it is better to draw it directly in Ti*k*Z or similar, because there is a trade-off between flexibility and ease-of-use. Ti*k*Z is more flexible, but harder to learn, perhaps. `smartdiagram` gives you a set menu, which is easier to use, but necessarily less flexible. The package itself provides some options for customisation. If you need something beyond that, it is usually easier to just draw it manually.

Comment: I am not familiar with TikZ to draw it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

samcarter's solution about deleting the arrows is correct, but it doesn't work in case that you use a non white background.

For colored background you have two solutions, the easy one is to know which color do you use and write `connection color = <background color>`.

When background color is not perfectly known, it would be better to use `connection color = none`, but this shows an error unless you change `smartdiagram` code.

Something that worked for me, although I don't know if it breaks anything else, is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/smart diagram/.cd,%
uniform connection color/.is choice,%
uniform connection color/true/.code={%
\tikzset{connection planet satellite/.append style={%
 draw=\sm@core@connectioncolor
},%
}%
},%
uniform connection color/false/.style={connection planet satellite},%
uniform connection color/.default=false,%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=brown}

\begin{frame}{test} 
\smartdiagramset{
    planet text width=2.5cm,
    satellite font=\scriptsize,
    bubble text opacity = 1,
    uniform connection color =true,
    connection color = none
} 
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.8}{
    \smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{
        Conditions de simulation,
        Type de tâches,
        Contraintes temporelles,
        Test de faisabilité du GEDF,
        Contraintes systèmes,
        Contraintes énergétiques
    }
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or just use the background colour `connection color = bg` :) Thanks for pointing out this possible problem -> (+1)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. to make the words in the satellites darker to be clear.

```
bubble text opacity = 1,
```

> 2. to reduce the distance between the text and the borders of the satellites.

just remove all your hard-coded settings and let the smartdiagram do it's job

> 3. to delete the arrows

Does not delete them, but hide:

```
uniform connection color =true,
connection color = bg
```

> 4. to make the satellites appear one by one

```
\smartdiagramanimated
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=brown}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test} 
\smartdiagramset{
    planet text width=2.5cm,
    satellite font=\scriptsize,
    bubble text opacity = 1,
    uniform connection color =true,
    connection color = bg
} 
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.8}{
        \usebeamercolor{background canvas}
    \smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{
        Conditions de simulation,
        Type de tâches,
        Contraintes temporelles,
        Test de faisabilité du GEDF,
        Contraintes systèmes,
        Contraintes énergétiques
    }
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edited to address the potential problem with non-white backgrounds, as raised in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354947/36296*

Comment: I am using \pscircle to draw nodes, I used the same colors defined in the smartdiagram (constellation diagram), but they are not looking nice like in the smartdiagrams, are there any options to add?

Comment: @FarahMind The colours in the smartdiagramm are shaded. Best ask a questions which does include a MWE.

Comment: I asked the question here [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354978/customize-the-options-of-pscircle]  but I am not sure about the title of the question