# Customize the options of \pscircle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, smartdiagram, pst-coil

Consider the follwoing code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-slpe}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette 
 quaternary}%               
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problématique} 
\begin{center}
\psscalebox{0.7 0.7} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
 {
  \begin{pspicture}(0,-5.4)(17.86,4.4)
  \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!30](8.4,- 
     0.2){1.8}
  \rput[bl](7.4,0.2){\textbf{Problèmes}}
  \rput[bl](6.8,-0.6){\textbf{d'ordonnancement}}
  \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!30](5.6,3.4){1.2}
   \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30](11.6,4.2){1.2}
   \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!30](14.0,0.2){1.2}

   \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange!30](1.6,-1.4){1.4}
   \rput[bl](4.7,3.8){Contraintes}
   \rput[bl](5.4,3.3){de}
   \rput[bl](4.8,2.7){précédence}
   \rput[bl](13.1,0.5){Contraintes }
    \rput[bl](13.7,0){de}
    \rput[bl](13.4,-0.6){blocage}
    \rput[bl](1,-0.9){Temps}
    \rput[bl](0.4,-1.5){d'attente entre}
    \rput[bl](0.5,-2.2){les opérations}
     \rput[bl](10.7,4.4){Contraintes}
    \rput[bl](11.3,3.9){de}
    \rput[bl](11.05,3.4){conflit}
    \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=teal!30](16.4,-3.0){0.8}
     \rput[bl](15.9,-3.0){Maite-}
     \rput[bl](15.9,-3.4){nance}
      \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!30](0.8,3.8){0.8}
      \rput[bl](0.2,3.7){no-wait}
      \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=brown!30](11.6,-3.8){1.2}
      \rput[bl](10.7,-3.4){Contraintes}
      \rput[bl](11.4,-4){de}
       \rput[bl](10.8,-4.5){ressources}
       \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=violet!30](5,-4.1){1.35}
       \rput[bl](4.3,-3.4){Période}
       \rput[bl](3.8,-4.2){d'indisponibilté}
       \rput[bl](3.95,-4.8){des machines}
       \end{pspicture}
         }
      \end{center}
      \end{frame}

     \end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I want:

1. to make the colors and the words in the nodes look nice like in the  smartdiagram (constellation diagram)
2. to draw arrows from the nodes to the central node just like in the  smartdiagram (constellation diagram) without changing the positions of the nodes.

Comment: You MWE does not compile for me.

Comment: First you ask a question how to remove the arrows and now you want them back? I am confused.

Comment: This is another example in which I need the arrows, and this case is different from the first one  since the distances between the centrale node and the other nodes are not the same.

Comment: I think with the smartdiagram  we cannot have different distances from the central node, if it is possible, then it is not necessary to correct the above code.

Comment: Does the above MWE compile for you?

Comment: Yes the code compile for me, and the output is given in the picture

Comment: Strange. Maybe I have some incompatible package version or something.

Comment: perhaps you are compiling with pdfLatex.

Comment: if you are compiling with PdfLatex, you will have a problem. I am compiling with Latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf

Comment: Why do you not use the package `pst-node`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this. I simplified your code loading `pst-node` and using the `\Cnodeput` command. This code requires loading, in addition to pst-node, `stackengine` and `pgffor`. It might be simplified further (and easier to understand) using `polar coordinates` for the placement of the nodes.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-slpe}%, auto-pst-pdf
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette
quaternary}%
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problématique}
    \begin{center}
        \psscalebox{0.7 0.7} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
        {
            \begin{pspicture}(0,-5.4)(17.86,4.4)
                \psset{fillstyle=solid, linestyle=none}
                \Cnodeput[radius=1.8, fillcolor=red!30](8.4,-0.2){PO}{\bfseries\Centerstack{Problèmes\\d'ordonnancement}}
                \Cnodeput[radius=1.55, fillcolor=orange!30](1.6,-1.4){TA}{\Centerstack{Temps d’attente\\entre\\les opérations}}
                \Cnodeput[radius=1.4, fillcolor=violet!30](5,-4.1){PI}{\Centerstack{Période\\d'indisponibilité\\des machines}}
                \psset{radius=1.2}
                \Cnodeput[fillcolor=cyan!30](5.6,3.4){CP}{\Centerstack{Contraintes\\de\\précedence}}
                \Cnodeput[fillcolor=blue!30](11.6,4.2){CC}{\Centerstack{Contraintes\\de conflit}}
                \Cnodeput[fillcolor=brown!30](11.6,-3.8){CR}{\Centerstack{Contraintes\\de ressources}}
                \Cnodeput[fillcolor=green!30](14.0,0.2){CB}{\Centerstack{Contraintes\\de blocage}}%
                \psset{radius=0.8}
                \Cnodeput[fillcolor=teal!30](16.4,-3.0){MN}{\Centerstack{Mainte\\nance}}
                \Cnodeput[fillcolor=magenta!30](0.8,3.8){NW}{no-wait}
                \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0, arrowlength=0.8, linestyle=solid, linewidth=3mm, linecolor=Lavender!60, nodesep=3pt}
                \foreach \mynode in {TA,PI,CP,CC,CR,CB,MN,NW}{\ncline{\mynode}{PO}}
            \end{pspicture}
        }
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just my personal opinion, but I would go with `tikz` instead of `pspicture`, as this is also what the `smartdiagram` from you other slide is using. To give you something to start with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problématique} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,fill,circle,minimum size=0.7cm,inner sep=5pt, align=center]
    \node[fill=red!20, text width=2cm] at (4,0) (A) {Problèmes d'ordonnancement};
    \node[fill=cyan!20] at (1,1) (B) {Contraintes};
    \draw [->] (B) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test} 
\smartdiagramset{
    planet text width=2.5cm,
    satellite font=\scriptsize,
    bubble text opacity = 1,
    uniform connection color =true,
    connection color = bg
} 
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.8}{
        \usebeamercolor{background canvas}
    \smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
        Conditions de simulation,
        Type de tâches,
        Contraintes temporelles,
        Test de faisabilité du GEDF,
        Contraintes systèmes,
        Contraintes énergétiques
    }
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to customize the constellation diagram of smartdiagram,to have nodes with different distances from the central node?

Comment: @FarahMind No idea. But I'd like to quote cfr: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354915/customize-constellation-diagram-of-smart-diagram/354917#comment873205_354915

Comment: I am trying to use your code to get the diagram I want. I have problem in the positions of the node (I am not familiar with tikz) , when I add another node C, the positions of A and B change. I cannot find any solution in the net!!!

Comment: @FarahMind The image is left aligned. So if you add node C left from the previous ones, they are moved to the right as the picture now becomes wider. Alternatively you can sue absolute positioning, search for something like `[remember picture, overlay]`